# How to logout the desired guard in laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to know how to logout the desired guard not all guards.
following code will logout all guards:

```
      Auth::logout();
      $request->session()->invalidate();
      $request->session()->regenerateToken();
```

If the user and admin loged in at the same time it will logout both.
I want when admin send logout request to:

```
  Route::get('/admin/logout',function(){
    //some codes
  })
```

it logout only admin not the user.
And logout only the user by following route

```
  Route::get('/logout',function(){
    
  })
```

Comment: try   Auth::guard('admin')->logout(); .before logout you can check  if((Auth::guard('admin')->check()){Auth::guard('admin')->logout(); }

Comment: As you want admin and front login different way then you have to create two login guard. 1) default as front login. 2) admin guard for admin. For more detail you can follow my example OR any you founded. https://github.com/ravikant14889/Laravel-AdminLte/blob/master/app/Http/Controllers/Admin/LoginController.php#L57

Comment: It doesn't need to invalidate session and regenerate token for the guard? @John Lobo

Comment: @Hamidj i think if invalidate it invalidate all i guess.just try once

Comment: yes, It will invalidate all, I'm looking for a solution to only invalidate sessions that related to admin guard @John Lobo

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
Auth::logout();
$request->session()->invalidate();
$request->session()->regenerateToken();
```

try

```
Auth::guard('guardName')->logout();
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?